# Unknown command message still pops up even you enter a valid command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Even though I entered a valid command, the unknown command message will still be executed. Is there any way to fix this?

Here's the code:

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    
    const unknowncommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle('SCOTT')
    .setDescription('You\'ve entered an unknown command. \nUse **!help** to see all available commands.')

    let validCommands = ["avatar", "broadcast", "clear", "help", "info", "online", "ping", "poll", "say"];
    const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    const command = args.shift();
    const isValid = validCommands.includes(command);    
    if(!isValid){
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        return message.channel.send(unknowncommand), console.log(`[SCOTT] ${message.author.username} entered an unknown command in "${message.guild.name}".`);
    }
});
```

**(07/07/2020)** Thanks @Karizma for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `userInputCommand` is not the command but an array:

`!help` => `["!help"]`

simply k

```js
const args = message.content.split(" ");
const command = args.shift();
const isValid = validCommads.includes(command);
```

You will also need to add an if statement at the top and return if the message doesn't start with the prefix:

```js
client.on("message", message => 
   if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
     //...
});
```

Comment: Should I just add those codes to my bot? The message still executes though.

Comment: Yea you add it to the bot, you do have to replace your previous section relevant to that though. It should be working, edit your post with the new code you have.

Comment: I never said to remove validCommands..I just posted the relevant code you needed to change. Edit the post with the new code you have.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. It still executes the message. I'll edit my post right now...

Comment: the error now is that you removed the prefix in message.content.substring(PREFIX.length), so either remove the prefixes in validCommands or remove the .substring(PREFIX.length)

Comment: No problem, glad we finally resolved it, in the future you probably shouldn't leave "thank you" comments, accepting the answer which you already doing is enough, and the standard here.

Comment: Oh, okay. Not gonna do that again.

Comment: Hey @Karizma, it still executes the message again... I don't know why it happens again even though I didn't modify the code...

Comment: When does it fail, what's the message?

Comment: Okay, there's no error. But here's the thing, if I type normally on Discord without the prefix, the unknown command message still pops up. The message is at line 14. That didn't happened after we fixed it yesterday.

Comment: You need to add an if statement to check if the message starts with the prefix. Edited my answer

Comment: Okay, it's working now. Thanks alot! (I can't handle myself to not say thank you to someone that helped me. :) )